# Calculate Distinct user over time period(month,day)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I want to calculate ratio between Daily active distinct users/monthly active distinct users. Can you suggest me which calculated field is better?

Comment: Presumably, the metrics should be tied to goals you have for your site. Only you would know your product and which metrics to use. Why not measure both!

Comment: distinctCountOver(userid,timestamp,pre_agg) doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Daily active distinct users` should be defined as follows:

```
distinctCountOver(userid,[truncDate('DD', timestamp)],PRE_AGG)
```

whereas the `Monthly active distinct users` should be:

```
distinctCountOver(userid,[truncDate('MM', timestamp)],PRE_AGG)
```